# Backup/access SMS on Nokia 3310 3g/2017 from Linux PC?

Tags: linux, desktop-computer, mobile-phone, sms

I'm trying to back up SMS messages on a Nokia 3310 3G onto a Ubuntu 18.04 PC; note that hardware system-on-chiand OS differs by version for a [Nokia 3310 (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_3310_(2017)):

> System on chip / Operating system:
>
> - MediaTek MT6260 / Nokia Series 30+ (2G)
> - Spreadtrum SC7701B / Java-powered Smart Feature OS (3G)
> - Spreadtrum SC9820A / Yun OS (4G, CMCC)

I have the 3G, so I have a "Smart Feature OS" which apparently is a version of KaiOS ([Is there any difference between KaiOS and 'Smart Feature OS'? : KaiOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/KaiOS/comments/8vva0o/is_there_any_difference_between_kaios_and_smart/)), which apparently ([KaiOS – A Smartphone Operating System | Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16461016)) is a fork of Firefox OS.

I have found http://os.firefox.com.cn/pcsync.html which apparently was a sync/backup PC application for Firefox OS while it still existed; it is actually a firefox extension which I installed in Firefox 43, but it doesn't find the phone. Then again, the extension makes use of "ADB Helper add-on", and `adb`:

```
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
```

... doesn't list this device either.

Connecting this device via USB prompts "Charging only" or "Mass storage"; adb fails to detect the device in either of these modes.

When in mass storage mode, I get `/media/disk` which apparently is an internal partition, and `/media/0000-9C43` which is my SD card. Looking at the internal partition:

```
$ tree /media/disk/
/media/disk/
├── Alarm
├── Audio
├── Backups
├── DRM_LRO
├── Ebook
├── Filearray
├── Java
│   ├── Media
│   └── tmp
├── JBed
│   └── Installed
│       ├── s0__d0.db
│       ├── s0__d1.db
│       ├── s0__d2.db
│       ├── s0__d3.db
│       ├── s0__d4.db
│       ├── s0__d5.db
│       ├── s0__d6.db
│       ├── s0_.jah
│       ├── s0_.obj
│       ├── s1__d0.db
│       ├── s1_.jah
│       ├── s1_.obj
│       ├── s2__d0.db
│       ├── s2__d1.db
│       ├── s2__d2.db
│       ├── s2__d3.db
│       ├── s2__d4.db
│       ├── s2__d5.db
│       ├── s2__d6.db
│       ├── s2_.jah
│       ├── s2_.obj
│       ├── s3__d0.db
│       ├── s3__d1.db
│       ├── s3__d2.db
│       ├── s3__d3.db
│       ├── s3__d4.db
│       ├── s3__d5.db
│       ├── s3__d6.db
│       ├── s3__d7.db
│       ├── s3_.jah
│       ├── s3_.obj
│       ├── s4__d0.db
│       ├── s4__d1.db
│       ├── s4__d2.db
│       ├── s4__d3.db
│       ├── s4__d4.db
│       ├── s4__d5.db
│       ├── s4__d6.db
│       ├── s4_.jah
│       ├── s4_.obj
│       ├── s5_.jah
│       ├── s5_.obj
│       ├── s6__d0.db
│       ├── s6_.jah
│       └── s6_.obj
├── Music files
├── OperaMini
│   └── mini4
│       ├── enteredlinks.ini
│       ├── enteredsearches.ini
│       ├── reksio.ini
│       └── speeddials.ini
├── Others
├── Photos
│   ├── DSC_0000001.jpg
│   ├── DSC_0000002.jpg
│   └── Saved Pictures
├── Received files
│   └── Nokia.txt
├── Recordings
│   ├── Radio recordings
│   ├── Received recordings
│   └── Voice recordings
├── System
│   ├── Gallery
│   │   └── main_filelist.txt
│   ├── MMS
│   │   ├── 47192.mms
│   │   └── mmslist.ini
│   ├── moreringset
│   │   └── envset.ini
│   ├── Mp3_res
│   │   ├── list1.lst
│   │   ├── list2.lst
│   │   ├── list3.lis
│   │   ├── listinfo.data
│   │   └── MyMusic.lst
│   └── Video
├── vCalendar
├── vCard
└── Video

31 directories, 61 files
```

... I cannot find anything corresponding to SMS messages or contacts. Additionally the system seems to use JBed, which is either a [small, fast Java Virtual Machine (JVM) for embedded real-time systems](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/jbed-java-for-real-time-systems/228801031), or [JBED - Run Java Games And Apps On Your Android Device](https://www.xda-developers.com/jbed-run-java-games-and-apps-on-your-android-device/).

Over bluetooth, this is what the device advertises:

```
$ sdptool browse XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX | grep "Service Name\|RFCOMM"
Service Name: OBEX File Transfer
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
Service Name: OBEX Object Push
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
Service Name: Advanced Audio
Service Name: Voice Gateway
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
Service Name: Voice Gateway
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
```

I cannot get `gammu` or `wammu` to connect with this device. Closest I got with `gnokii` was using this config file, `nokia3310-gnokii.config`:

```
[global]
port = XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
initlength = default
connection = bluetooth
rfcomm_channel = 3
model = AT
```

Here is what `gnokii` says:

```
$ gnokii --config nokia3310-gnokii.config --identify
GNOKII Version 0.6.31
LOG: debug mask is 0x1
Config read from file nokia3310-gnokii.config.
phone instance config:
model = AT
port = XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
connection = bluetooth
initlength = default
serial_baudrate = 19200
serial_write_usleep = -1
handshake = software
require_dcd = 0
smsc_timeout = 10
rfcomm_channel = 3
sm_retry = 0
Initializing AT capable mobile phone ...
Serial device: opening device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Channel: 3
Channel: 3
Using channel: 3
Message sent: 0x00 / 0x0004
41 54 5a 0d                                     | ATZ             
write: [ATZ<cr>]
read : [ERROR<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x00 / 0x0007
03 45 52 52 4f 52 0d                            |  ERROR          
Received message type 00
Message sent: 0x00 / 0x0005
41 54 45 31 0d                                  | ATE1            
write: [ATE1<cr>]
read : [ERROR<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x00 / 0x0007
03 45 52 52 4f 52 0d                            |  ERROR          
Received message type 00
Message sent: 0x00 / 0x000a
41 54 2b 43 4d 45 45 3d 31 0d                   | AT+CMEE=1       
write: [AT+CMEE=1<cr>]
read : [OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x00 / 0x0004
02 4f 4b 0d                                     |  OK             
Received message type 00
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0007
41 54 2b 47 4d 4d 0d                            | AT+GMM          
write: [AT+GMM<cr>]
read : [^@^DME ERROR: 4<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x000f
05 00 04 4d 45 20 45 52 52 4f 52 3a 20 34 0d    |    ME ERROR: 4  
Received message type 06
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0008
41 54 2b 43 47 4d 4d 0d                         | AT+CGMM         
write: [AT+CGMM<cr>]
read : [^@^DME ERROR: 4<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x000f
05 00 04 4d 45 20 45 52 52 4f 52 3a 20 34 0d    |    ME ERROR: 4  
Received message type 06
Initialization failed (6)
Serial device: closing device
Telephone interface init failed: Function or connection type not supported by the phone or by the phone driver.
Quitting.
Function or connection type not supported by the phone or by the phone driver.
```

I tried to test the AT via bluetooth serial:

- First, do changes as per: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory
- `sudo chmod 777 /var/run/sdp` after reboot, even with the changes above done
- `sdptool add --channel=3 SP`
- `sdptool browse local` and make note of "Service RecHandle: 0x1000e" for the last serial port service
- `sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX 3` in one terminal
- `sudo socat - /dev/rfcomm0,crnl` in other terminal
- `sdptool del 0x1000e` when done

Here, I saw that nearly every AT command (including `AT+CMGL` "List messages") returns `+CME ERROR: 4`, which is [Operation not supported](https://www.micromedia-int.com/en/gsm-2/73-gsm/669-cme-error-gsm-equipment-related-errors), except for `AT+CMEE=1` [Report mobile termination error](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atcmee-report-mobile-termination-error/) and `AT+CLCC` ([List current calls](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtopia4.3/atcommands.html)), which does not look good.

So, what Linux software could I use to access SMS on this phone device (and possibly delete it)?

Comment: I stopped using my Nokia 3310 two years ago because of SMS limit. Did you eventually found the answer? I asked tech support and it was beyond unhelpful. I was told to buy a smartphone and to delete photos to make more space, but deleting 0.5MB of photos (equivalent size of 5000 SMS) did nothing to help.